# get all checked checboxes and add their names and values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have large form mainly drop down lists and checkboxes. Checkboxes are created dynamically so i don't know their id's before they are created. I use drop down onChange event to do create them on the fly.

How can i loop trough the form and get all the checkboxes that are checked, that is their id and their value? I need to do this only for check boxes that are checked. All checkboxes share the same name, that is: categoriesfilters[]. Currently i have on click event on the checkbox which invoke the javascript function.

Here is the code:

```
function update_number_of_adds_found(field_dropdown,selected_value) {
                selected_value="";

               var addtypeid = $("#addtypeid").val();

               // trying to store the values of the checkboxes

                $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( 
                  function() { 
                   var id = $(this).attr('id');
                   var value = $(this).val(); // or maybe attr('value');
                   // the data is stored, do whatever you want with it.
                    alert(value);
                  } 
                );

               var selected_value = {
                                        addtypeid: addtypeid,
                                        // need to add the ids and the values here as well
                                    };



                 var url = "<?php echo site_url('search/findNumberOfAdds'); ?>";
        $.post(url, selected_value, function(r){
            if(r) {

                $('#totalNumOfAdds').empty();
                $("#totalNumOfAdds").append(r.result); 
            } else { 
               // alert(selected_value);
            }
        }, 'json')



            }
```

Regards, John

Comment: Show us your current code...

Comment: hi, i just update my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var categories = [];

$("input[name='categoriesfilters[]']:checked").each( 
  function() { 
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var value = $(this).val();
      categories[categories.length] = {id : value};
  } 
);

console.log(categories);

$.post(url, categories, function(r){
```

...

Comment: Your solution works perfect. How can i update now the variable var selected_value (see the code in my question please.

Comment: still strugling to update my var selected_value..can you help?

Comment: Ok i edited my post, try it out. Don't need the selected_value variables.

Comment: Actually i do...i have other values that i am sending, so i want to add the categories to selected_value variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( 
  function() { 
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var value = $(this).val(); // or maybe attr('value');
   // the data is stored, do whatever you want with it.
  } 
);
});
```

I guess you want to check that on form submit.

Comment: Did you mean `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I always confuse between this.value and $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$('input[name^="categoriesfilters"]:checked').each(function() {
    var obj = {
        id: $(this).attr('id');
        value: $(this).val();
    };
    arr.push(obj);        
});
console.log(arr); // show us the array of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to use Jquery?

Add a class to each of the checkbox i.e "class_chk";

```
$(function(){
     $('.class_chk').each(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var val = $(this).val();
                alert("id = "+id+"---- value ="+val);
         }  
   });
});
```

The above way you can get all the check box id and value those are checked.

Thanks..